How to hide sensitive information in com.google.android.gms.signin.xml file on Android
I have a PENTEST finding in Android on a rooted device. It has highlighted a google SDK file /data/{my_app}/shared_prefs/com.google.android.gms.signin.xml.
This file seems to be storing user information and other tokens and can be accessible on a rooted device.
Is there anyway either to prevent this to store these information or to encrypt it?
